# decrypt hashing password

Tags: java, security, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

I have the following code to encrypt a password, but when I am trying to decode it, I don't get the expected result here is the code.

```
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
String afterhex=toSHA1("mypassword".getBytes());
String encodedBytes = encoder.encodeBuffer(afterhex.getBytes());

public static String toSHA1(byte[] convertme) {
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String(md.digest(convertme));
}
```

For example if you tried to encode, jill you should get `LQBIF2TS0FSDYtGjaNmC2gl/klw=`

Any advice for restoring it back :)

Comment: you don't decrypt hashes.

Comment: **Hashing != encryption!**

Comment: This cannot be answered, because you cannot decrypt a hash.

Comment: hashes are one way ticket. You cant decrypt them.

Comment: SHA-1 is not secure.  You should use bcrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: Hashes are cracked not "decrypted",  and they are cracked using software like John The Ripper,  rainbow tables or even free services online.

Comment: @SLaks  or scrypt!  Also sha1 has been broken for a few years now...

Comment: Reopen! I believe this question is useful in that it contains a common misapprehension, and misapprehension is very answerable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hashing algorithm is not encryption / decryption algorithm.

**Hashing** is a **one way** process of mapping large data sets of variable length (e.g. message), to smaller data sets of a fixed length (hash). The length depends on hashing algorithm.

And it is **NOT POSSIBLE** to perform reverse operation from hash back to your message.

Even though it is possible to find a *message* generating the same hash (for example using [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table); much easier for weaker hashing algorithms like MD5), you **never know** if the message is identical to the original one which was used to generate the hash. One of the methods which prevents finding (*guessing*) a message (password) generating the same hash value is using [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) when hashing a massage (password).

**EDIT**

I would also recommend any of *Bruce Schneier* books e.g. "*Cryptography Engineering: Design Principles and Practical Applications*" (written in a very nice and *digestible* way) which will describe cryptography and hashing in great details.

Comment: +1 for nice answer. However they can be cracked by using rainbow tables or by brute force attack.

Comment: @smit I think the term cracked is being misused, a collision is found is more correct.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Couldnt get the thought about specific word. ;-}

Comment: @smit, yes, you are right. Hashing is not strong cryptographically and there are many ways of generating a message from a given hash. However, my point here was to clearly state that you can't "decrypt" from hash.

Comment: @Tom I think in the world of Cryptography nothing is secure. There are always ways to to breach them out. They can improve it only.

Comment: Can I just mention salt should be added. Thanks! (Oh and in the case of passwords, the hash may well be larger than the original text. And try to find someone else's implementation rather than rolling your own.)